# beamer overly shows item in next page

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a slide with figures and an item list

the code

```
\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{../Fig_0}
    \includegraphics<2>[width=\textwidth]{../Fig_1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<2-> Line 1.
  \item<3> Line 2.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

So `Fig_0` shows up first, on first click `Fig_1` overwrite the first figure, and shows the first item `Line 1`. However on the second click the item list all moved to a new frame. Why is that? How can I get all of them on a single slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to "Why is that?" is easy: because that is what you set with your overlay specifications. With your current overlay specifications, the first figure appears only on slide 1; the second figure appears only on slide 2; the first item appears from slides 2 on (slides 2 and 3) and the last item appears on slide 3.

The answer to "How can I fix it?" is a little more complicated: since nothing is broken, it's hard to know what you mean by "fix it", since you didn't mention what the desired output should be.

Perhaps you want a different overlay specification like the following one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics<2->[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<2-> Line 1.
  \item<3> Line 2.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `beamer` internally deactivates the floating mechanism, there's really no need for you to use the `figure` environment (unless you want to use `\caption`), and you could use a `center` environment instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! What you had is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the tip on `figure` too!